# How can I compile libsndfile under ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, libsndfile

How can I compile libsndfile under ubuntu 11.04 ?

Should I use g++ or something?

Comment: Maybe this question is a better fit for the Unix/Linux or Ask Ubuntu stack exchanges?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get build-dep  libsndfile
apt-get source libsndfile
```

Will install all required dependencies for building, then (the second line) will fetch you a buildable source tree and unpack it. You can then build it using:

```
cd libsndfile
dpkg-buildpackage
```

**Or** instead of ALL that you can just install it if you don't need to fiddle with sources:

```
sudo apt-get install libsndfile
```

you may also want libsndfile-dev, depending on what you're doing with that library (see `apt-cache show libsndfile-dev`)

Answer (score 3):

Unzip the archive to a directory, switch into that directory, type

```
 ./configure
 make
 make install
```

Or the easiest way to do get the binaries (if you don't need any special configuring for your particular set up) is to get it via the Ubuntu magic program getter (look under `system` files for the library).  That way it will also get the dependencies for you, I believe.

Comment: Looks promising! I used apt-get to install libsndfile. How can I find the Makefile?

Comment: @Shawn Double check with Mr. Sinelaw's answer, but you may be all set (and not need to compile anything)

Comment: +1 - this is the canonical answer for "how do I compile X in Linux" :)